# String Validation ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

Hey all I am using Action Script and  just simply trying to check if a string contains special characters or numbers, if it does not add it to my list otherwise error output...however the NAN is  giving me the error Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type Number...any suggestions? here is some code:

```
private function onAddName(event:Event):void {
        var newItem:Object = {label:addName_ti.text};
        //if not a number true then add onto list.
        if ( isNaN(addName_ti.text )
        {
            names_li.dataProvider.addItem(newItem);
            names_li.dataProvider.sortOn("label");
            addName_ti.text = "";
            addName_bn.enabled = false;
            //User feedback for successfully entering item.
            trace ("Item succesfully added!");
        } else 
        { 
            //User feedback for not succesffully entering item.
            addName_bn.enabled = false;
            trace ("Improper formatting");
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't know if its a copy/paste typo, but you condition with isNaN is missing >> ) << this should result into a compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isNaN expects a number. That is why you get the error.  You should use parseFloat first:

```
isNaN(parseFloat(addName_ti.text));
```

parseFloat is good especially for external text, because it will ignore white space and trailing characters. It will return NaN if the parse is unsuccessful.

`"  12"` would return `12`.   "12abc" would return `12`.   "abc12" would return `NaN`.  `"  12 34 5  6"` would return `12`.

If you're text is guaranteed to be well formatted, the simply casting as a number `Number("12")` would be slightly faster.    In my test, doing it 10 million times was about 400ms quicker.

Answer (score 0):

The isNaN method expects a Number parameter so you will have to cast the String to Number:

```
if(isNaN(Number(addName_ti.text))
```

You can also use a regular expression (regex) to validate your variable:

```
var isNumeric:RegExp= /^[0-9]*$/;
trace(isNumeric.test(addName_ti.text));
```

Comment: This will work fine as well (as long as you're text is a well formatted number).  This will likely be ever so slightly faster as it doesn't check for white space and trailing characters.